# Preg match to find all occurance of date in this format 26 jan 2016 or 26th jan 2016 or 26 january 2016

Tags: php, regex

Please tell how to make regex code to find all occurrence of date from the string, in the format listed below :

```
26 jan 2016
26th jan 2016
26 january 2016
26th january 2016
26 feb 15
26th feb 15
```

ie :

```
$string = "Test 26 jan 2016 test test test 12 Feb 15 test test test 17 January 2013 nice testing 123 6 12 2016";
```

I want the result as an array where i will get :

```
$res = array (

'2016-01-26',
'2015-02-12',
'2013-01-27'

)
```

Please tell how to make the same using PHP regex.

Comment: *Please tell how to make regex code* => No. Welcome to SO, here before you post a question you have to **try**, fail, then **try harder**, fail again, then ask a question and tell us **what you've tried**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all`, `array_map`, `date` and `strtotime` functions (I've modified the initial string a bit to get a complex case):

```
$string = "Test 26th jan 2016 test test test 12 Feb 15 test test test 17 January 2013 nice testing 123 6 12 2016";

preg_match_all("/\b\d{2}(?:\w{2})? \w+? \d{2,4}\b/i", $string, $matches);
$dates = array_map(function($d) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d));
}, $matches[0]);

print_r($dates);
```

The output:
Array

```
(
    [0] => 2016-01-26
    [1] => 2015-02-12
    [2] => 2013-01-17
)
```